# Integrate turn by turn Voice navigation in android application

Tags: android, google-maps, navigation, text-to-speech, voice

I want to integrate turn by turn navigation in my android application. But like in Google maps and navigation, there should be voice output to guide the user to turn, keep walking straight, etc from src to destination. Is this possible ? If yes, please give me a tutorial or some ideas about how to do this. Thanks !

Comment: Check out the Google navigation services, or if you want to create without using the Google navigation services, check for the turns data from Google.

Comment: Keep in mind, depending on what you're doing, it could be against ToS: [(d) No Navigation, Autonomous Vehicle Control, or Enterprise Applications. You must not use the Service or Content with any products, systems, or applications for or in connection with any of the following:

(i) real-time navigation or route guidance, including but not limited to turn-by-turn route guidance that is synchronized to the position of a user's sensor-enabled device.](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)